vue/compiler-sfc Doesn't recognise Flow.js syntax
I am trying to migrate a Vue 2 application to Vue 3.
The application uses Flow.js and Webpack / Vue CLI for the build.
I am trying to follow the approach with the compatibility build.
So I:

Installed vue and @vue/comapt 3.1
Updated vue-loader
Replaced vue-template-compiler with @vue/compiler-sfc

I added the following to my vue.config.js
    config.resolve.alias.set('vue', '@vue/compat');

    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        return {
          ...options,
          compilerOptions: {
            compatConfig: {
              MODE: 2,
            },
          },
        };
      });

This is my babel.config
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
      { useBuiltIns: 'entry', decoratorsLegacy: false, decoratorsBeforeExport: true },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-flow',
  ],
};

When I try to run serve, I get errors like this:
[vue/compiler-sfc] Unexpected token 
It's clear that the compiler cannot handle Flow type annotations.
I tried to modify the vue config rules but without success.
